# How can I use the string attribute in Sphinx 0.9.9 version?

Tags: sphinx

Sphinx 0.9.9 version is installed on my server.
sql_attrs_string is not working, is there any another attribute to use for this version?

Answer (score 0):

hum sorry but at this time Sphinx 2.0.6 was available.

Now 2.0.8

It' really a good idea tu  upgrade.

http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/

So if you MUST  still use 0.9.9 I had an awful solution -> convert string to ascii.

I had this problem sometime ago, it's was "possible" but It's so easy  with sql_attrs_string ...